# std::shared_ptr owned by one class and initialized by another class

Tags: c++, initialization, shared-ptr, ownership

I have a class lets say A. Class A has a member variable of type:

```
std::shared_ptr<SomeType> m_dataMemberInA
```

I do not initialize the member in Class A. In a class B I also have a

```
std::shared_ptr<SomeType> m_dataMemberInB
```

as member variable. In the initializer of Class B I link the two pointers:

```
B::B(std::shared_ptr<SomeType> passedFromA)  : m_dataMemberInB{passedFromA}
{
...
}
```

In another function of B. I want to initialize the shared_ptr:

```
void B::anotherMethod()
{
m_dataMemberInB = std::make_shared<SomeType> (arguments...);

}
```

But the m_dataMemberInA stays empty! -> Since m_dataMeberInA and m_dataMemberInB point to the same memory I would expect that whenever m_dataMemberInB becomes valid the same should apply for m_dataMemberInA?!?!?

Tried to initialize the m_dataMemberInA in another class. But m_dataMemberInA stood empty.

Comment: ```m_dataMemberInA``` stores (probably) a ```nullptr```. When constructing B, you're storing ```nullptr``` inside ```m_dataMemberInB```. There is no link whatsoever with A. When you're calling ```anotherMethod```, now ```m_dataMemberInB``` stores an address but ```m_dataMemberInA``` is stil nullptr.

Comment: So, in "raw pointer" terms, you're expecting that if you do `int* a = nullptr; int* b = a; b = new int(32);`, then `a` will not be null?

Comment: Even though it's technically possible, e.g. with references, just [please don't do this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_at_a_distance_(computer_programming))

Comment: Alice and Bob (and possibly some more people) share a bicycle. Bob doesn't want to share that bicycle any more, so he buys a new bicycle (which he is prepared to share). Does the first bicycle still exist and belong to Alice and the others, or does it disappear and become the new bicycle shared by everyone, including Bob?

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation. That makes a lot sense. Now the thing is I want Class A to be the owner of the instance but Class B should fill the pointer. Is there a good approach? Passing the pointer as reference? std::shared_ptr<SomeType>&   ??

Comment: `void anotherMethod() {
        auto ptr = m_b.get();
        ptr = new int(20);
    }` But I already hate this code..

Comment: if B has to modify A, it must keep a link to A (or the data he wants to modify) one way or another. You can store a reference or pass A (or the appropriate data) again as an argument of ```anotherMethod```. Many solutions are possible, the best one will depend on the big picture: what do you want to achieve, not how do you want to do it.

Comment: From architecture perspective I have a Main-Class A. I want the Main-Class to be the sole owner of the member variable described above. But Main-Class should not construct m_dataMemberInA. Therefore I have a "lower" situated class B. The results from class B are stored into m_dataMemberInB. Afterwards the Main-Class A invoke other classes to further work on m_dataMemberInA... Does this help?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I will rewrite your code using normal pointers, I think that makes clearer, what happens

```cpp
B::B(SomeType* passedFromA)  : m_dataMemberInB{passedFromA}
{
...
}
void B::anotherMethod()
{
    m_dataMemberInB = new SomeType(arguments...);
}
```

As you can see, this just changes the pointer in B, and nothing about the pointer in A. Since `m_dataMemberInB` is only a copy of `m_dataMemberInA`, changing anything about the pointer itself will not change anything about the other pointer. If there were already an object in `m_dataMemberInA`, you could then change the pointed to object by `*m_dataMemberInB = otherObject;`. This changes the pointed to object instead.

To change a pointer by changing the other you need another level of indirection, but I don't see a way to do this without undermining the idea between shared pointers (namely that they are independent and one can exist without the other).

Maybe I can help you if you provide more information on what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you very much! From architecture perspective I have a Main-Class A. I want the Main-Class to be the sole owner of the member variable described above. But Main-Class should not construct m_dataMemberInA. Therefore I have a "lower" situated class B. The results from class B are stored into m_dataMemberInB. Afterwards the Main-Class A invoke other classes to further work on m_dataMemberInA... Does this help?

Comment: I still can't see why you need several classes. For instance, maybe making ```B``` inherit from ```A``` can do the job also. Can't say without more information on your goal. Separating ```A``` from ```B``` is already a design choice. But what is the specification, the functionality you want to realize?